# IoT device not receving data when used with PoE splitter

Tags: networking, power-over-ethernet, iot

I've got a small IoT device that has an ethernet port and microusb for power. I already have PoE infrastructure and I bought a PoE splitter so I could get power and data to it with a single cable.

When it's plugged in to a wall wart for power and plugged directly into the ethernet coming from my PoE switch, everything works fine. When I put the splitter in the middle and power the device from the splitter, it powers up but its blinkenlights indicate that it's not getting an IP address. I ran tcpdump on my router and I can see the DHCP requests coming from the IoT device and replies from my router, but they just repeat; the replies don't seem to be getting back to the IoT device.

The switch is a Netgear GS308EP; it sees that the port is linked and powered and that its link speed is 10M/half-duplex (with or without the splitter). I've tried 3 different splitters, all active 802.3at/af. Any ideas?

Comment: 10M/half indicates the switch isn't even receiving the Ethernet link-negotiation signals... Are they "gigabit capable" PoE splitters (able to pass through all four pairs) or the "100 Mbps" kind (two pairs dedicated to power)?

Comment: Have you been able to test with a pc/laptop and see whether that end receives anything/negotiates correctly?